# "Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath" on a most unexpected line on postback when ModelState has errors

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

It's been two hours straight I have been haggling with this monstrosity.

I get this error:

> Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath

On this line in my view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueName, 
  "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The stack trace given below seems to suggest that a call to `Url.Content` has been made, but I have made no such call. Below is the stack trace and that is followed by some more lines of code around the line which causes the error:

> [ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name:
>   contentPath]    System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(String
>   contentPath, HttpContextBase httpContext) +125
>   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(String contentPath) +26
>   ASP._Page_Views_Journal_EditIssue_cshtml.Execute() in
>   MyProject\Views\Journal\EditIssue.cshtml:45
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +291    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +173    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9644097    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

The lines of code around the line that throws the exception are:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IssueName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "IssueName" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT**

Strangely, the exception is raised only when I come back from a post-back and never when I first load the view, and not even when the `ModelState` has no errors. It only is raised when the `ModelState` has errors after a post-back.

Here is some server side code, though I don't see any reason why it might be doing something wrong:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditIssue(EditIssueViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.AvailableTags = BusinessManager.GetAllTags();

    if (viewModel.IssuePDFFile == null || viewModel.IssuePDFFile.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please select a file to upload.");
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(viewModel.IssuePDFFile.FileName);
    if (!StaticData.AcceptedContentTypes.Contains(viewModel.IssuePDFFile.ContentType, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        !fileInfo.Extension.Equals(".pdf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You can only select a PDF file.");
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
            .Select(e => new { e.ErrorMessage, e.Exception });

        var errorList = errors.ToList();

        errorList.ForEach(e => Debug.Print(e.ErrorMessage));
        errorList.ForEach(e => ModelState.AddModelError("", e.ErrorMessage));

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var operationResult = await BusinessManager.EditIssueAsync(viewModel);

    if (!operationResult.Succeeded)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", operationResult.FailureMessage);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    viewModel = (EditIssueViewModel)BusinessManager.GetIssueWithRelationships(viewModel.IssueId);
    viewModel.SuccessMessage = operationResult.SuccessMessage;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: took me a while to stop actually looking at the error page line highlighted in red and actually read the error message at the top too

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Holy crap!

If you ever, ever, ever get this error, please remember, there is but one, and only one, cause for this error.

> **Somewhere in the network of lines on your view, you have passed a null
>   value to the @Url.Content method. Period.**

The line it reports an exception at may have nothing to do with the exception and may be a mile or two away from the culprit.

Search, search, search like crazy. :-)

That's how I found the solution to this and relief from my misery.

Comment: If you get a similar stack trace, then `Url.Content` is probably to blame. But this is the first answer that comes up when I search by the exception message and my issue has nothing to do with `Url.Content`.

Comment: A good safeguard against this is to check that you have a value to pass into the `Url.Content()` method before calling it, e.g. `@if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(item.Url) { <a href="@Url.Content(item.Url)">@item.Text</a> }` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This error annoyed me as well,

But the simple solution was to add an @id on your code below

> new { @id="HolyCrapId", @class = "text-danger" }